# formula that yields closest upper multiple of four

Tags: linear-algebra

So I went to an interview today and I was asked to give a formula that yields the upper closest multiple of four for a given number. For example:

$f(16) = 16$

$f(25) = 28$

$f(61) = 64$

I could not do it. Could someone help me please.

p.s. the interview is over this is just for curiosity

Comment: You can try $4\left\lceil\frac n4\right\rceil$

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is by using the ceiling function:
$$f(n) = 4\left\lceil{\frac{n}{4}}\right\rceil,$$
where $\lceil{x}\rceil$ is the upper closest integer to $x$.